# Can't replace an array inside a tuple with another array of same size - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

[image]

I want to replace the second np.array of the first tuple with an array of the same length but filled with zeros:

I have tried the following:

```
Coeff[0][1] =np.zeros(len(Coeff[0][1]))
```

But I get the:

```
'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Any idea how to complete  the replacement process ?

Comment: Tuples in Python are immutable, you may need to use lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable in Python, you cannot change values stored in it.

You can do `list(map(list, list_of_tuples))` for a quick casting into list, or `[list(x) for x in list_of_tuples]` if you want to use list comprehension.

I've done some ugly %timeit benchmark on my computer, both seems merely equivalent in speed.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to reverse it after the replacement?

Comment: @jokerp Sure, you can cast all list into tuples later : `list(map(tuple, list_of_list))`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to keep the original values in the arrays, then you could use [`numpy.nan_to_num()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html?highlight=replace%20nan) with `copy=False` to modify the second array in the tuple in-place. This has the advantage of not creating new arrays.

The following example replaces the second array of every tuple in `Coeff` with zeros.

```py
import numpy as np

Coeff = [
    tuple(np.full((5, ), np.nan) for i in range(2))
    for j in range(5)
]
print(Coeff)

nil = [np.nan_to_num(tup[1], copy=False) for tup in Coeff]
print(Coeff)
```

The output is

```
[
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])), 
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]))
]
[
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
    (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))
]
```

If you only need the work with the first tuple, you could use `nil = np.nan_to_num(Coeff[0][1], copy=False)`. Note that I use `nil` to indicate you do not need the result of the function.